# Hadoop: hadoop namenode -format breaks the datanodes, why?

Tags: hadoop, configuration

I have a working configuration of Hadoop 3.2.1 with one namenode and two datanodes.
If I run

```
stop-dfs.sh
hadoop namenode -format
```

Then *start-dfs.sh* cannot start the datanodes on the slaves anymore. The datanode daemon does not show up when running jps on the datanodes.

Why does this happen?
What can I do to run my datanodes again?

CONTEXT: I simply want to remove all data on HDFS. Ideally, I would format both the name and data nodes, but I am stuck at the first step.

Comment: The datanodes still have data on them, so why should they start without cleaning out their data directories? But what specific errors do you get?

Comment: If i runt stop-dfs.sh, format the namenode and the datanodes, then start-dfs.sh will not start the datanodes anymore. There are no errors. But if I run jps on the datanodes, I see that the datanode daemon is not running.

Comment: There are still log files that are generated. Just because that command doesn't return error output doesn't mean there aren't any

Comment: Any idea where those log files would be generated?

Comment: That depends on how you installed and configured Hadoop. But by default a log directory gets created outside the bin directory